# Add a website to Azure AD

Tags: azure, website, application

I'm a Belgian student and I'm currently an intern in a small company.

I have configured Azure AD with Password Hash Sync + SSO WatchGuard (Allows all users automatically connect to the Internet), and it's working pretty well.

All the users connect to their computer with AD credentials and have access automatically to Internet and Office 365.
But now I would like to do another thing, we have a website in the internal network working with authentication by AD and I would like to add this website to Azure if possible ? In this way, all the users can access to this website automatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD and AD are very different and use different authentication protocols (Open ID vs LDAP etc.). Because of this, you cannot just substitute Azure AD for AD in your web application, you would need your web application to be updated to support authentication using Azure AD.